# How to pass variable to a ViewController that is embedded in a Navigation Controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, segue

I want to pass data from `ViewController1` to `ViewController2`. `ViewController2` is embedded within a `Navigation Controller` (because I have a Segmented Control that corresponds to 3 Child View Controllers). My segue is directly from `ViewController1` to the `Navigation Controller`.

[image]

I tried the following in `ViewController1`:

```
ViewController2().testID = "test value"
```

With the following in `ViewController2`:

```
var testID = ""
```

However `testID` does not update when I run `print(testID)` in `ViewController2`.

What is recommended for passing data from `ViewController1` to `ViewController2`? Any help/advice is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the value by overriding the prepare(for segue:) function in ViewController1

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    // Get the new view controller using segue.destination 
    guard let destination = segue.destination as? UINavigationController else {
        return
    }

    guard let finalDestination = destination.viewControllers.first as? ViewController2 else {
        return
    }

    finalDestination.testID = "Test Value"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

NSUserDefaults will always work.